# Running jmeter using docker

Tags: docker, jmeter

I am facing issue while running jmeter using docker container. The script works fine when I run it through GUI or CLI on my local machine. But when I execute same script using container it getting failed.
Below is the issue.
So I am using beanshell postprocessor for capturing response cookies. Below is the code for same.
props.put("MyCookie1","${COOKIE_one}");
props.put("MyCookie2","${COOKIE_two}");
props.put("MyCookie3","${COOKIE_three}");
And this parameterized value works fine in my local machine(windows 10). But when I run the same in container these parameterized value doesn't gets resolved.
I am using "alpine:3.12" base image in container.

**NOTE** : Jmeter version in my local machine is "5.4.1" and java version is "java 11". In docker container Jmeter version is "5.3" and java version is "java 8". The API which I am hitting is hosted in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the most important detail: your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Blind shot: in order to be able to access cookies as `COOKIE_one`, etc. - you need to add an [extra property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to wit `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` either to *user.properties* file or to pass it to JMeter startup script via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
./jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

---

Also according to JMeter Best Practices:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. [You should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)

So maybe it worth consider migrating to Groovy, you will only need to amend your code from:

```
props.put("MyCookie1","${COOKIE_one}")
```

to

```
props.put("MyCookie1",vars.get("COOKIE_one"))
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information if needed.

And update your Dockerfile to use the [latest stable version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri. "-JCookieManager.save.cookies=true" this solution worked for me. And thanks for the best practices docs.